# Meshgrid-like function to generate 4D arrays in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 4 dimension mathematical function I want to implement in matlab, but the `meshgrid` function works for at most 3 dimensions. Is there a similar function for more dimensions? (I don't want to use for loops).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html).  `ndgrid` extends for dimensions beyond 3, but you can most certainly use it for 2 or 3.  `meshgrid` is a special case of `ndgrid`.

However, one caveat I would like to mention is that the way the `X` and `Y` coordinates are arranged between `meshgrid` and `ndgrid` are interchanged.  Specifically, `X` traverses horizontally in `meshgrid` while `X` traverses vertically in `ndgrid`.  Similarly `Y` traverses vertically in `meshgrid` while `Y` traverses horizontally in `ndgrid`.

Therefore, to get the same behaviour for 2 or 3 dimensions, do:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(...)
[Y,X] = ndgrid(...)
```

Or:

```
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(...)
[Y,X,Z] = ndgrid(...)
```

Using `ndgrid` for higher dimensions maintains that same order with regards to the horizontal and vertical coordinates.

To be more explicit, this is what the note for `ndgrid` says at the end of the documentation:

> The `ndgrid` function is similar to `meshgrid`, however `ndgrid` supports 1-D to N-D while `meshgrid` is restricted to 2-D and 3-D. The coordinates output by each function are the same, but the shape of the output arrays in the first two dimensions are different. For grid vectors `x1gv, x2gv` and `x3gv` of length `M`, `N` and `P` respectively, `ndgrid(x1gv, x2gv)` will output arrays of size `M`-by-`N` while `meshgrid(x1gv, x2gv)` outputs arrays of size `N`-by-`M`. Similarly, `ndgrid(x1gv, x2gv, x3gv)` will output arrays of size `M`-by-`N`-by-`P` while `meshgrid(x1gv, x2gv, x3gv)` outputs arrays of size `N`-by-`M`-by-`P`.